# Magento multiple stores - remove ?store= from url

Tags: php, magento, url, magento-1.9

I am trying to shorten the url when the frontend is being changed to a different language. 
I already managed to shorten it a bit through setting `<?php echo $_lang->getCurrentUrl() ?>` to `<?php echo $_lang->getCurrentUrl(false) ?>` but it still shows the $store=.

I just want my urls to be like that: domain.com/de and domain.com/en.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to change the your `page/switch/languages.phtml` file

Find the line that reads

`echo $_lang->getCurrentUrl()`

And replace with

`echo $_lang->getCurrentUrl(false)`

**Option 2**

Go to **System -> Configuration -> Web -> URL Options** and set the 'Add Shop Code to URLs' option to **Yes**

This will make the urls to the store appear like the following:

www.myshop.com/otherstore/

www.myshop.com/default/

To edit the names of your stores to be SEO friendly, go to **System -> Manage Shops**

---

Quelle: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/53386/magento-multistore-store-and-from-store-in-url/53426#53426

Comment: I did exactly this but it still doesnt work. Is it possible that the issue comes from my custom theme? Because the custom theme added a languages.phtml in its own directory where the switch links come from. Even with the above settings, the ?store= is still visible

Comment: Yes, you must modify the language template file of your own theme, because files are overwritten recursively. Add the param (false) to getCurrentUrl method, it should work.

Comment: sorry, maybe I wasnt clear. thats exactly what I did. I changed the languages.phtml of my custom theme and it doesn't work

Comment: Okay, can you please clear the cache. Go to yourdomain.tld and changed the language one more time. After that, post the current url (without host/top level domain).

Comment: Thats funny. All settings are correct, the store code was added to url like url rewrite (english/). The parameter ?store= should not really be there anymore.

Comment: would it help if you could see the whole languages.phtml code?

Comment: No, the changes in language.phtml works fine (__to_store was removed from url). The store parameter is a part of seo friendly url rewriting and should be removed with the backend setting "Add Shop Code to URLs" (set to yes). I have no more idea, sorry.

Comment: Okay, it's just that the code is completeley differen from the one in the `base/`directory.
I just replaced the custom theme's file with the default one, and its still the same url. so its not a code isusue

Comment: Have you installed some extensions or modified/rewrite core classes? Because, the magento store url parameter looks like __store= (with underscores), your parameter looks like store= ...

Comment: I have installed extensions but I think they shouldn't have changed anything in the core and since I am pretty new to magento I dont know how to find out

Comment: Okay, i've seen you shop (url from your profile). I think, the language switch was overwritten. Can you post the language.phtml code?

Comment: will post it as an answer now

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your store code are 'de' and 'en' for the said stores, you just have to adapt your configuration under

> System > Configuration > Web > Add Store Code to URLs

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if(count($this->getStores())>1): ?>
<div class="language dropdown">
<div class="dropdown-toggle cover">
    <!--<div class="icon" style="background-image:url(<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl().'images/flags/' . $this->htmlEscape(Mage::app()->getStore()->getName() .'.png'); ?>)"></div>-->
    <div class="language-inner">
        <div class="value">
            <?php echo Mage::app()->getStore()->getName(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="dropdown-menu left-hand" onchange="window.location.href=this.value">
    <?php foreach ($this->getStores() as $_lang): ?>
        <?php $_selected = ($_lang->getId() == $this->getCurrentStoreId()) ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $_lang->getCurrentUrl(false) ?>" class="currency_icon<?php if($_lang->getId() == $this->getCurrentStoreId()):?> selected <?php endif; ?>">
            <!--<span class="icon" style="background-image:url(<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl().'images/flags/' . $this->htmlEscape($_lang->getName() .'.png'); ?>)"></span>-->
            <?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_lang->getName()); ?>
        </a>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Okay, it's not a problem. The problem will not be found without debugging. It looks like an overwrite of some additional classes...

Comment: what a bummer. okay thanks for your help, I will try to get someone to fix it anywhere.